# Radio controlled plane flight simulator

Tags: windows-7, flight-simulator

I am looking to learn to fly my radio controlled plane with a six-channel controller. I would like software that allows me to practice before I try flying for real.

Lower cost is of course better, but I'd like to have something that's realistically going to help me learn to fly.

The controller I have is 6-channel and hooks up to the computer via USB. I believe the FTDI drivers actually simulate a regular serial port for the data coming out.

I hope to run this on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the [Realflight](http://www.realflight.com/) simulator on Windows before. It:

- Comes with its own USB controller, but it also comes with a way to use your controller with standard ports.
- Works on Windows
- Is not cheap - the newest version [is available on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G7JCWR2) for around $180. However, I use the old version (I have 3.5) and it's perfectly acceptable and I believe it really helped me learn to fly. [G5 is available](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002V3Z3V0) for about $50 less.
- If you're willing to go all the way down to 3.5 (the version I use), it's [available for ~$99](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KJF7U4).

I haven't used version higher than 3.5 in ernest, so all of the following is my experience with G3.5:

- Very real and convincing. The physics are top notch (for the most part. Water landings are... interesting.) I *think* it even supports surround sound which is rather neat when flying.
- Quite customizable - you can make your own maps and play with the planes. You can adjust the thrust each engine gives out, change wings, etc. Essentially, you can use your own airplane if you know enough about it.
- Smooth (even on my 2003 hardware I use it on)

I'd suggest you go for 3.5 or 4 if you're tight on money. It doesn't have multiplayer modes (flying around shooting each other), but from your question I don't think you're looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

I've flown few hours with FMS – [RC-Sim](http://www.rc-sim.de/). **Freeware.** I think I can recommend it. 
Similar to others, it allows control using USB controller, build your own airplanes, worlds, etc...

In download area, search for **FMS** (Flug modell simulator.)